# Ibm Watson chatbot intent vs entities

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

For ibm chatbot can I tell chatbot that a word in a conversation is a entity or do I have to make it an intent.
For example
What are your interests? Question
Sports answer

Can I add sports as a entity right from the menu?

Comment: I would recommend to do the training within Watson Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

Entities by themselves will work if you know what the person is going respond with, and doesn't deviate much.

Where you don't know, but you know the structure in how they ask then you can use contextual entities.

The last option is to shape your message to the end user to change their behavior.

For example "What are you interests" is very broad. Two examples:

- "Do you like to play sports?" = Gives a yes/no answer, which you can drill down on.
- 'What kind of sports do you like?" = Allows you to make a narrow entity to catch the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make *interests* an *entity*, because it makes more sense.

[image: Entity for interests**strong text**]

This quote from [IBM developer blog](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/chatbot-watson-conversation-natural-language-understanding-nlu/) talks about the use case for *entities*:

> In some scenarios, it makes sense to define the entities of interest in your Conversation workspace; for example, when defining a “toppings” entity for a pizza ordering bot. However, in other scenarios, it is impractical to define all possible variations for an entity and it is best to rely on a service to extract the entity; for example, when extracting a “city” entity for a weather bot.

Also, [How to build a Chatbot with Watson Assistant (free chatbot course)](https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/how-to-build-a-chatbot/) is a great beginner course.